# Parser rule does not produce an error for invalid input

Tags: antlr4

I have discovered a strange parser behavior and cannot explain it to me. Maybe someone of you can give me a hint if I am doing something wrong.

I have following grammer file:

```
grammar test;

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */
unary_expr
  : unary_operator IDENTIFIER;

unary_operator
  : PLUS PLUS;

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */
IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z]+;
PLUS: '+';

NEWLINE
  : ( '\r'? '\n' | '\r' )+ -> skip;
```

When I test this grammar with

```
++abc++def
```

the lexer will detect all tokens properly

```
Tokens:
[@0,0:0='+',<2>,1:0]
[@1,1:1='+',<2>,1:1]
[@2,2:4='abc',<1>,1:2]
[@3,5:5='+',<2>,1:5]
[@4,6:6='+',<2>,1:6]
[@5,7:9='def',<1>,1:7]
[@6,12:11='<EOF>',<-1>,2:0]
```

But the parse tree definitely does not cover all detected tokens!

```
Parse Tree:
unary_expr (
  unary_operator (
    "+"
    "+"
  )
  "abc"
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your expected behaviour? That it's passed as a list of unary operators? Or a syntax error? For the former, you'd need a rule that actually matches a list of unary operators. For that latter, you'll need a start rule that ends with `EOF`. Otherwise ANTLR happily parses just a prefix of the input and leaves the rest in the token stream.

Comment: I have expected that the missing tokens would result in errors in the parse tree. But "++def" is completely missing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tell ANTLR to match whatever tokens are consumed by parser rule `unary_expr`, then that is exactly what ANTLR does.

If you want to force ANTLR to consume *all* tokens, add the `EOF` token at the end of your parser rule:

```
unary_expr
 : unary_operator IDENTIFIER EOF
 ;
```

Now you will see your expected error:

[image]

Comment: Ah! I think I was catched in a logical trap ... the above example is part of a more complex grammar and I tried to reproduce it with a simple example. I had tested this part of my grammar and had set the "startRule" property of the Visual Studio Code extension to the "unary_expr" rule. But the "EOF" token is only part of the main grammar. Thus using the "startRule" property without adding an extra "EOF" in the grammar will result in this brain wasting behavior. Thanks a lot for this hint :)